# Reopen Tabs plugin for gedit not found

Tags: 11.10, gedit, plugins

I upgraded to Ubuntu 10.10 a few days ago, and since then have not been able to use one of my favourite plugins for Gedit, reopen-tabs, which restores the tabs that were open when gedit was last closed.

All of the files are in the correct place in ~/.gnome2/gedit/plugins, but when I go to edit->preferences->plugins, it doesn't show up as it used to do. I can't think of any reasons why it isn't being detected, but I'm not exactly an expert Linux user, so I imagine I'm being dense. Any input would be really appreciated (even if it's an alternative plugin that does the same thing automatically (ie not session saver)).

Comment: Sam, did rawonstack solve your problem? If so, please mark his answer as accepted. Otherwise provide your own solution of more info in your post. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure if you have upgraded to 10.10 and not to 11.10? I assume it is 11.10 as the question is tagged by 11.10.
Ubuntu 11.10 has Gedit3 on board and this one requires different plugins, placed into different directory ~/.local/share/gedit/plugins/ 
Please visit https://live.gnome.org/Gedit/Plugins for available plugins. The one I think you are interested is here https://github.com/Quixotix/gedit-restore-tabs